# Running error of function calcHist and cvtColor in OpenCV with Mac OS Mojave

Tags: python, macos, opencv, macos-mojave

When I run a python program using OpenCV function "calcHist" and "cvtColor", the following error occurred.

My brand new Macbook's OS is 10.14.6 (Mojave) which is python 3.7 pre-installed. As I searched some information and know that there are some problems on running OpenCV in python 3.7. And I also find a method to downgrade my python to 3.6.5 already.

The code I use is as follow. I find that I can run it smoothly in another computer using ubuntu 18.04.

```
from future import print_function 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import argparse 
import cv2 

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image") 
args = vars(ap.parse_args()) 
image = cv2.imread(args["image"]) 
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
cv2.imshow("The Original", image)
hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0], None, [256], [0, 256]) 
plt.figure() 
plt.title("Grayscale Histogram") 
plt.xlabel("Bins") plt.ylabel("# of Pixels") 
plt.plot(hist) 
plt.xlim([0, 256]) 
plt.show() 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: from __future__ import print_function
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("The Original", image)

hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])

plt.figure()
plt.title("Grayscale Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Bins")
plt.ylabel("# of Pixels")
plt.plot(hist)
plt.xlim([0, 256])
plt.show()

cv2.waitKey(0)

Comment: what error ? you forgot add error message in question.

Comment: The code is supposed to be added in the post, not in a subsequent comment. :)

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Excuse me. I am the first time to post the message. However, I was noticed that something wrong even I try to post the code. I try to solve it now.